# Remove outliers from a column of a Pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `l`, grouped by `Code` and `Month` :

```
l.head():

                 Qty
  Code    Month 
 600003     02    1
            06    2
 600006     02    1
            05    1
            07    2
```

I want to detect outliers by `Qty` , so I tried by IQR:

```
def get_num_outliers(column):
q1 = np.percentile(column, 25)
q3 = np.percentile(column, 75)
return ((column<q1) | (column>q3))

l.agg([get_num_outliers])
```

I don't seem to get a valid answer by that.
I'm still a beginner in Pandas and was wondering if anyone could help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
def remove_outlier(df, col):
  q1 = df[col].quantile(0.25)
  q3 = df[col].quantile(0.75)

  iqr = q3 - q1
  lower_bound  = q1 - (1.5  * iqr)
  upper_bound = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)

  out_df = df.loc[(df[col] > lower_bound) & (df[col] < upper_bound)]
  return out_df
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution. The thing is `q1` and `q3` both equate to `1.0` which leads to same `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` ! Do you know how I can perhaps create a visualization to manually detect outliers, or any other solution? Thanks again.

Comment: When I look at the sample data, I find the upper bound as 3.5, lower bound as -0.5. No value less than -0.5 or greater than 3.5 in sample data. Are you sure there is an outlier in the data? You can try **boxplot** for visualization.

Comment: Guess I'm looking for outliers where there are none. Thanks for tipping me in the right direction!

Comment: Hello @specbug, if my answer was helpful, don't forget [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.